# How to write function which return types are runtime determined( on the value of argument? )

Tags: c++, boost

More specifically, let's say i want to generalize the process of boost::range::join to accept arbitrary number of boost::range as parameters ( by using iterators, ellipsis or some container like std::vector, it does not matter in the question ), in what way could it give back it's calculation result, beside return + type erasure?

Comment: It might return for example `boost::any`, or a template/class with myriad conversion operators defined.

Comment: @Deduplicator In the case mentioned above, how could you figure out the correct type and convert the result to that type to use?

Comment: As I said, the returned proxy has those myriad conversion operators defined, and it is the compilers task to pick the right one, depending on what is needed. (Might even defer the actual call until then, if that might make things more performant, e.g. because the proxy might be completely optimised away.) Anyway, if possible avoid it all.

Comment: but how can the return proxy be able to store unlimited amount of different type? if it's simply through inheritance or pointer, what's the different of it and type erasure? anyway, thanks for the suggestion, but I unfortunately have a container over a container, and I have to ripe iterator over the whole range out of it.

Comment: It doesn't. It only stores one representation or all info needed to make the deferred call, and the compiler by selecting the appropriate conversion operator offered decides how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is a statically typed language. That means there is no way to change the return type of a function based on it's arguments' *values*.

You can, however, implement a function template, that uses different return types based on the static type and/or number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class. Make the return type of the function a pointer to the base class. Depending on the arguments, you can return pointers to instances of a derived class.

Comment: isn't that type erasure?

Comment: Based on my understanding of type erasure, it is.